# Floating point and integer ambiguity

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, ambiguity

I have a function (and a constructor) that should be able to take integer and floating point values. In fact I want it to take an `int64_t` or a `long double`, so what I want is,

```
class Foo {
    public:
    Foo(int64_t value=0);
    Foo(long double value);
};
```

However if I do this and try `Foo f = 1;` the compiler complains about the conversion from `int` to `Foo` being ambiguous. Ok, but if I change the first constructor to take a `int32_t` there is no such ambiguity. Can anyone explain to me why this is the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of the 1 literal is int.  Either constructor is going to need a conversion, int to int64_t vs int to long double.  The compiler doesn't think either of them is preferable so it complains.  Solve it by adding a Foo(int) constructor.  Or casting the literal, like (int64_t)1.

Comment: Ah yes, thankyou. Makes sense. I'm a little surprised that the compiler doesn't recognise an `int64_t` as a closer match to an `int` than a `double` is though. (I guess because a conversion is a conversion and that's all it worries about(?))